# SSL connect error (yii frame work)

Tags: php, yii, google-api, google-plus

I'm using Google Plus API in [yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). I have created my API credentials including the API Key, client Secret and redirect Uri which were  provided same as from the project created on the Google Developer Console.

I sign with G+ plus, ask for the account then for the permission once I press allow I'm getting this error.

> Error 500
>   SSL connect error.

url : https://keerthi.xxxxxxxx.xx/index.php/Site/AuthSocial?network=4#

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Do you see anything in the laravel.log ?